# How to do a subtraction operation in a view to display an updated number field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an accounts MVC and i have that set up the way i want it. now in my carts MVC. i have this in my carts partial, basically show line items of desired items the user wants to purchase and then a second table showing their account balance and the deduction of the total of the line items of the table above. now i cant get the new balance to show, i cant just subract the two data inputs right there on the partial, so i tried to put it in the model and it cant return anything. how would i do this calculation so it will show up. i have this in my cart.rb model page:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

def add_menu(menu_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(menu_id: menu_id)
    current_item = line_items.build(menu_id: menu_id)
end

def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
end

def self.balance_for_user(user)
   accounts.where(user_id: user.id).order(:created_at).pluck(:acctbal).last || 0.0
end
```

this is my show method in my carts_controller

```
def show
    @accounts = Account.where(user_id:current_user.id)
    balance = Cart.balance_for_user(current_user)
    total = cart.total_price
    newBal= balance - total
    if @cart.id != session[:cart_id]
     flash[:notice] = "You can not access cart #{@cart.id}"
     redirect_to store_url 
    end
  end
```

and this is where i want to be able to show the variable with the new amount so i can change to currency

```
<div class="container">

 <% if notice %>
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
 <% end %>

 <h2>Your Cart</h2>

 <table class="table table-striped"  style="width: 65%">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-2">Student ID</th>
        <th class="col-md-3">Menu</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">date</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">price</th>
    </tr>
      </thead>
   <tbody>  
    <%= render(cart.line_items) %>

    <tr class="total_line">
        <td colspan="3">Total</td>
        <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %>
   </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
   <h3>Your Account Balance</h3>

   <table class="table table-striped"  style="width: 65%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-2">Current Balance</th>
        <th class="col-md-3">Order Amount Deduction</th>
        <th class="col-md-2">New Balance</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>            
                <tr>
                    <% @accounts.each do |account| %> 
                    <td><b><font color="green">
  <%= number_to_currency(account.acctbal)%></font></b></td>
                    <% end %>       
                    <td><b><font color="red">
            -<%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></font></b></td>    
                    <% @accounts.each do |account| %> 
                    <td><b><%= number_to_currency(newBal)%></b></td>
                    <% end %>       
                </tr>        
            </tbody>        
           </table>
           <%= link_to "Checkout", new_order_path, method: :get, :class => 
                 "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>

             <%= link_to 'Empty cart', cart, method: :delete, :class => "btn
               btn-primary btn-sm", data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **carts_controller** change `balance` to `@balance`, `total` to `@total`, & `newBal` to `@newBal` so that they are  instance variables that are available in your **show** view.

In your partial, which I assume is used in your **show** view, change this code:

```
<tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="3">Total</td>
    <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(cart.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
```

to this:

```
<tr class="total_line">
    <td colspan="3">Total</td>
    <td class="total_cell"><%= number_to_currency(@total) %></td>
</tr>
```

You can figure out the rest for `@balance` and `@newBal`.
If this partial is not used in your **show** view this will not work.

Comment: it does not like this line:  total = cart.total_price it says cart is undefined local variable or method `cart' for #<CartsController:0x3a50e40>

Comment: @Edgar you used **@cart** elsewhere in your cart controller. Should it be **@total = @cart.total_price**? Where are you defining **@cart**?